# Is there any way to turn off the "Finish Setting Up Your iPad" nag in iOS 11?

Tags: ipad, ios

iOS 11 will nag you to "Finish Setting Up Your iPad" with notifications and a badge on the settings app if you don't have a passcode. Is there any way to turn this off?

(Just so someone doesn't tell me that I really should set up a passcode: I am setting up the iPad in question for a stubborn older person who uses the iPad at home exclusively and hates the minor inconvenience of having to type in a passcode or use TouchID. I would like to upgrade because software updates are important for security but the person in question refused to upgrade once they learned they needed to set up a passcode.)

Comment: Not having a passcode is probably worse than any security issue iOS 11 fixes...

Comment: Dear Apple, please don't make this so difficult. If I don't want a passcode, it means I don't want a passcode. There could be a lot of reasons. Don't second guess your users.

Comment: Apple is knowingly shoving this down our throats, more so the Apple Pay, but they kind of go hand in hand. Steve Jobs had a passion. It worked. Now, Apple is pushing a different agenda. Give us back the Apple Steve Jobs created.

Answer (score 4):

Click on the ‘Finish setting up iPad’ notification and then instead of entering a passcode choose ‘other options’ and select ‘Don’t use a passcode ‘

Answer (score 2):

From the Settings screen where you are seeing the red badge, click on the prompt to Set Passcode.  The keyboard will obscure the options so minimise it out of the way, then select Other Options, and choose not to set a passcode.  Do NOT actually select any of these options.  Instead, click on the X in the upper left hand corner to cancel out of the screen.  You should be returned to Settings screen, but with no red badge.

Answer (score 0):

Just act like you're setting up Apple Pay and then cancel out of it.

Comment: At this writing (2020-10), this only works temporarily.